# How do I create a program that has a GUI coded with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, and handles all the logic in C#?

Tags: user-interface, electron, client-server, desktop-application, electron.net

I currently have a C# console application. I created a GUI for this application using HTML, CSS, JavaScript, React, and Electron, but I have no idea how to connect them together. I want everything to be able to be done from within the GUI, so I do not want the user to have to start the HTML/CSS/JavaScript application and the C# application separately. Is this possible?

I have looked into ASP.NET, but I want the program to be a desktop application, not a web application. I also tried to do this with Electron.NET, and when I packaged the app for Windows, it ran completely fine, however, when I packaged the app for Linux, it did not function properly, and that is a problem as the program needs to run on Linux. I'm not sure why it did not work properly when I packaged it for Linux and that may be worth looking into, but anyway, I was under the impression that it is fairly common to write the frontend for a program with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript and write the backend in another language, however is this only possible if the backend is a server which is continuously running? Please help! Thanks.